# JLabel alignment in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to align a JLabel to the right in a JPanel. I'm adding a JTabbedPane, a JPanel which contains my JLabel and JTextArea to a main JPanel.

I have searched SO and tried some methods like `setAlignmentX`, `setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT)` and nested containers to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class LabelProblem

{

 public static void main(String[] args)

 {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label Problem");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  JPanel Main = new JPanel();
  Main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Main, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

  JPanel ComponentPanel = new JPanel();
  JLabel label = new JLabel("Sample Text");
  label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
  label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
  label.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

  ComponentPanel.add(label);

  JTabbedPane Tab = new JTabbedPane();
  Tab.add("Document 1", new JPanel());

  Main.add(Tab);
  Main.add(ComponentPanel);

  JTextArea Area = new JTextArea(10,10);
  JScrollPane Scroll = new JScrollPane(Area);

  frame.add(Main);
  frame.add(Scroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  frame.setSize(450,450);
  frame.setVisible(true);

 }

}
```

How can I align my JLabel to the right?

Thanks!

Comment: Irrelevant but you are not executing the code in the appropiate thread, please use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` in the main. See Swing's [hello world](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the place of that label is determined by the layout of `ComponentPanel`. Since you didn't specify any layout it is using the default `FlowLayout` with a `CENTER` alignment. Assuming that you are ok with a `FlowLayout` it is a mere question of setting the alignment of the `LEFT` since this is possible with this layout.

Here's the code with the fix, however I suspect that as you put more elements to the ComponentPanel you will want to use another layout since FlowLayout is more adequate for menus and the like and not for displaying the main content.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

class LabelProblem
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                initGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void initGUI()
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label Problem");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel main = new JPanel();
        main.setLayout(new BoxLayout(main, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel componentPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Sample Text");
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        componentPanel.add(label);

        JTabbedPane Tab = new JTabbedPane();
        Tab.add("Document 1", new JPanel());

        main.add(Tab);
        main.add(componentPanel);

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area);

        frame.add(main);
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(450, 450);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Note: I also changed the variable names to follow the [java style convention](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html): variable names should start with lower case to differenciate them from clases names, starting in upper case.

Comment: +1 for leveraging the default layout alignment; the question was confusing about left vs. right alignment.

Comment: @DSquare Thank you for fixing my code! I tried changing the alignment to <code>setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT)</code> but it didn't work. Could you please tell me why it did not work?

Comment: @mundomug My understanding is that the LayoutManager of a container is the responsible of determining the size and position of all the components inside it. AlignmentX/Y is a property of the components, it's up to the layout manager to make use of that property or not. [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) does use it, but all the others that I can think of right now ignore it and use their own rules and properties to determine the alignment. Also, it might be useful when not using a layout manager (null layout) which is absolutely not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be a matter of you not actually setting layouts where you imagine you're setting layouts.

You have a JPanel with a vertically oriented BoxLayout (Main) enclosing another JPanel with default layout (ComponentPanel), finally enclosing your label. The reason why your label can't be pushed to the right is because is already **is** pushed to the right **within it's enclosing container**. If you set a colored border around ComponentPanel, you'll see what I mean -- it only occupies the same amount of space as the JLabel, giving the JLabel nowhere to move.

You need to set a layout and constraints for your intermediate ComponentPanel, allowing it to horizontally fill its parent container so that the label has someplace to go.

You haven't really specified how your layout is supposed to look, but if you change the layout on Main to X_AXIS, your label will pop over to the left (as will its parent container). Without knowing what you're really trying to do, I can't say much more.

I would however, suggest you throw your BoxLayout away entirely and look into using [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), which gives you a high level control over your UI. GridBagLayout isn't the most concise construct,  but that's the price of control.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach is to set the label's `horizontalAlignment` to `JLabel.RIGHT` in the constructor.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class LabelProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label Problem");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
        tab.add("Document 1", new JPanel());
        frame.add(tab);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Sample Text", JLabel.RIGHT);
        frame.add(label);

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
        frame.add(scroll);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(450, 450);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```